# Tastypie building bundle with dictionary

Tags: tastypie

According to the manual it should be possible

> Given either an object, **a data dictionary** or both, builds a Bundle for use throughout the dehydrate/hydrate cycle.

So I threw this together using Resource

```
def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):

    bundles = []

    foo = {}
    foo['bar'] = 1

    bundle = self.build_bundle(data=foo, request=request)
    bundles.append(self.full_dehydrate(bundle))

    serialized = {}
    serialized[self._meta.collection_name] = bundles
    serialized = self.alter_list_data_to_serialize(request, serialized)
    return self.create_response(request, serialized)
```

But in `full_hydrate()` it chokes on `bar` even though I am passing it. What am I missing here?

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/dan/project/tastypie/resources.py" in wrapper
  203.                 response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/dan/project/tastypie/resources.py" in dispatch_list
  445.         return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)
File "/home/dan/project/tastypie/resources.py" in dispatch
  477.         response = method(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/dan/project/resources/widgets.py" in get_list
  188.         base_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)
File "/home/dan/project/tastypie/resources.py" in build_bundle
  704.             obj = self._meta.object_class()

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/widget/fundperfyearly/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not specified `queryset` or `object_class` inside `Meta` class of your model resource. At least one of them should be specified whenever using `ModelResource`.

You can avoid this by passing `obj` as argument to `build_bundle` method, e.g.

```
bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=MyModel(), data=foo, request=request)
```

### Reference

Tastypie v0.9.15

1. [build_bundle](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.15/tastypie/resources.py#L708-L725)
2. [Setting `object_class` using `queryset.model` if `queryset` specified.](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.15/tastypie/resources.py#L1743-L1744)